# Bearer token request http flutter

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

I need to send my token for my API.
I save my token in SharedPreferences and I can recupered this.
My API need one, with the Bearer but how do ?

I tested with Authorization, Http etc.

Methods To save in SP

```
Future<bool> setToken(String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString('token', value);
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('token');
  }

  Future<Candidate> candidateAuth({Map map}) async {
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/auth/candidate';
    await http
        .post(url,
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: jsonEncode(map))
        .then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        token = Candidate.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).token;
        Candidate().setToken(token);
        return Candidate.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed auth');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My API Call :

```
Future<List<Theme>> getThemes() async {
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/theme';
    String token;
    Candidate().getToken().then((value) {
      token = value;
    });
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    });
    print('Token : ${token}');
    print(response);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List themesList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<Theme> themes = [];
      for (var themeMap in themesList) {
        themes.add(Theme.fromJson(themeMap));
      }
      return themes;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load themes');
    }
  }
```

My API return error 401 : unauthorized

Comment: unauthorized means your token has expired and you need to fetch new token

Comment: no when i enterred my token in my swagger is good @VivekMishra

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`token` might not be set by the time it invokes `http.get`. Change it to

```
    String token = await Candidate().getToken();
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    });
    print('Token : ${token}');
    print(response);
```

So that it is for sure set with right value.

Comment: Whenever I use this approach I end up with a blank version of Candidate instead of getting the original desired state. Anyone have a clue based on this little information what I am missing?

Answer (score 15):

Also you can use this method

```
String token = await Candidate().getToken();
final response = http.get(url,
        headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token"});
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add the authorization field into the request header:

```
var token = await getToken();

http.post(
    "$url",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    },
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
).then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(json.decode(response.body));
        // Do the rest of job here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the other possible solution for the problem. You have to wait response of getToken() function before continuing. You can accomplish it in two different ways. Either use "then" or "await".

```
Future<List<Theme>> getThemes() async {
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/theme';
    String token;
    Candidate().getToken().then((value) {
        token = value;

        final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });
        print('Token : ${token}');
        print(response);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           List themesList = jsonDecode(response.body);
           List<Theme> themes = [];
           for (var themeMap in themesList) {
              themes.add(Theme.fromJson(themeMap));
           }
           return themes;
         } else {
             throw Exception('Failed to load themes');
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you assign your token in a different way.

When you do this `await asyncFunction();` Dart will wait till it is complete. But, when you do like this `asyncFunction().then((value) => print)` this tells Dart that it can continue executing your code, and when that asyncFunction is completed than print the value.

This is what happens on your case with

```dart
Candidate().getToken().then((value) {
      token = value;
    });
```

Here is a example, execute it on Dart Pad.

[Future.dart](https://gist.github.com/bmatheus91/b3aac14e941449bb18609f77a8a8f8ab)

Answer (score 2):

**The cleaner code**

```
String? token = await Candidate().getToken();

Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
};
await http.get(url, headers: requestHeaders);
```

Then  if you want the responce or the data come from the backend you can replace `await http.get(url, headers: requestHeaders);`
by `var responce  = await http.get(url, headers: requestHeaders);` and use the responce.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample for a post request. You just need to add the header 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'

```
final response = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue don't know if it will work for everyone, changing the url to https:// solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I spent complete one day , Just Tell your backend developer to do this.

when Dio/Http sends headers it will lowerCasing all headers keys.

So if you have access to the server you must lowercase your key.

Eg. [PHP]
**$token = array_change_key_case($this->input->request_headers(), CASE_LOWER)['authorization'];**

**@Flutter code**

final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
});

Answer (score -2):

```
final response = await http.get(url);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  //print(body);
  final Iterable json = body;
  return json.map((country) {
    return Country.fromJson(
        country); // if you use "{}", you must use return
  }).toList();
```

Comment: Add some description to explain your code.

Comment: You have not put a description to explain your code, and also you are not doing the right thing. Where are you passing the authentication token?