# how to show data from get api with token in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem getting data from api (GET DATA) with token

I get an error when I try to get dataو While passing the token

this error in my `{response.body}` :

`ERROR FOR SHOW : {"message":"Unauthenticated."}`

```
class _ResultLadderState extends State<ResultLadder> {
  String token = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    getInfo();
    getDataLadder();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getInfo() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      token = pref.getString("login")!;
    });
  }

  Future getDataLadder() async {
    print('bye');
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://pellekani.com/backend/api/v1/pellekan/main/active'),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });
    print('Token : ${token}');
    print('ERROR FOR SHOW : ${response.body}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('hi');
      setState(() {
        stringResponse = response.body;
      });
    }
  }
```

I received the token successfully but I do not know why the data is not displayed

in the Postman app, works without any problems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bearer token request http flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079131/bearer-token-request-http-flutter)

Comment: I read the article but could not solve the problem. Please make these changes in the code @UjjawalMaurya

Comment: @UjjawalMaurya ?!

Comment: Run you GetDataLadder() function inside end portion of getInfo(). It would be better to add a logic. i.e., If token !='' { then run GetDataLadder(); }

Comment: @UjjawalMaurya please answer this question with edit code , don't comment

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add "Content-Type" in your request headers.

Comment: i added show same error

Comment: It would be helpful for us If you share the screenshots of the postman request and dart http library request logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String baseUrl="Your Api Key"
Future<Dio> getApiClient() async {
    try {
      var token = await storage!.getData(StorageKeys.token.toString());
      print(token);
      _dio.interceptors.clear();
      _dio.interceptors.add(
        InterceptorsWrapper(
          onRequest: (options, interceptorHandler) {
            // Do something before request is sent
            options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token.toString();
            return interceptorHandler.next(options);
            // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
          },
          onResponse: (response, interceptorHandler) {
            // Do something with response data
            return interceptorHandler.next(response); // continue
            // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
          },
          onError: (error, interceptorHandler) async {
            // Do something with response error
            if (error.response?.statusCode == 403 ||
                error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
              _dio.interceptors.requestLock.lock();
              _dio.interceptors.responseLock.lock();
              // ignore: unused_local_variable
              RequestOptions options = error.response!.requestOptions;
              // ignore: unused_local_variable
              Options? opt;
              var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
              token = await user.getIdToken(true);
              await storage!.setData(StorageKeys.token.toString(), token);
              options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token.toString();

              _dio.interceptors.requestLock.unlock();
              _dio.interceptors.responseLock.unlock();
              //  return _dio.request(options.path, options: opt);
            } else {
              return interceptorHandler.next(error);
            }
          },
        ),
      );
      //  _dio.options.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }

    return _dio;
  }


  getDataLadder() async {
    try {
      var http = await getApiClient();
      var response = await http.get(baseUrl);
      return response;
    } catch (er) {
      // print(er.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is this!? :(

Comment: Posting a giant block of code with absolutely no context a or reference to the Question and minimal explanation is not at all a useful answer. Please make an effort to [edit] your post and explain it.

Comment: Use this code with your Api key and that is how error can be remove