# How to send Get request with authorization (JWT token) headers in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to send JWT Bearer token to the API (ASP.NET Core API) to complete the authorization. I have the following codes:

```
//get
  Future<dynamic> get(String api) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + api);
    String? token = await SecureStorage().readSecureStorage('token');
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
    };

    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response;
    } else {
      print(token);
      //Throw Exceptionp
    }
  }
```

When I test this code, the status code of the response is still 401. I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079131/bearer-token-request-http-flutter) but I could not solve it. How can I fix this?

Update: I used jwt.io to decode my token.

**The header:**

```
{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

**The payloads:**

```
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "alex2020",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "developer",
  "UserId": "5",
  "exp": 1682964030
}
```

Comment: request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';

Comment: Remove this "Accept": "application/json",

Comment: @RidhaRezzag The status code is still 401.

Comment: Make sure your token its being imported from secure storage and assigned to the variable  token, so just after var headers add this print(token); and check you log and see if the token is printed

Comment: Yes, It shows token. I copied that token from Flutter debug console and pasted in the `Postman` and the result was 200. There is a problem in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Since  the error is not clear  try using single quotes, i remember long time ago faced something similar and it was single quotes that fix it

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
```

Comment: I tested it. No success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `await SecureStorage().readSecureStorage('token');` creates two `"`s in the token string.

I solved the problem by removing `"` from token. The complete code is:

```
Future<dynamic> get(String api) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + api);
    String? token = await SecureStorage().readSecureStorage('token');
    if (token != null) {
      token = token.replaceAll(RegExp('"'), '');
    }
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
print('Bearer $token');
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response;
    } else {
      //Throw Exception
    }
  }
```