# Bearer Token Authentication Approach

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Can anyone explain when to call the function of sending HTTP Get request of Bearer token ?

Actually, what I want to do is make an app for authentication including Register, Verify mail & Login and along with that showing all Posts in the app.

I have implemented the register, verifying mail & Login authentication by sending respective Get & Post requests. After implementing Login request, I got Bearer token as a response, now to get all posts, I need to send Bearer token in the header of the request. But now I am confused about how & when to call the function for requesting Posts.

Comment: Here, u may find a solution here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079131/bearer-token-request-http-flutter